# Iphone5 clearing problem

Tags: iphone

I've been give my son's old iphone5, but I can't seem to clear it of his old stuff and get it to go back to factory settings in order for me to set it up so I can use it, how do I do that!

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> General -> Erase All Content and Settings

or plug into itunes & restore.

Comment: Plug into iTunes & set up as new device, on a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [Apple guideline](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252) to restore you  iPhone.
 Hope can help you.